# Why is xPath returning these elements in the reversed order?

Tags: php, xpath

Can someone tell me why the below xPath expression is resulting in the array being in the reverse order?

```
/ReaderDetails/Reader[Pin = "2325" or Pin = "2421" or Pin = "2424"]
```

When I then do a `foreach`, the array that is returned pulls the element for 2424 first, then 2421 and last 2325.

These PINs are entered in a comma separated list, and need to be in this order.

Comment: The order comes from your document, not from the XPath expression

Answer (score 1):

If you're in XPath 1.0 (and I assume you are, because people using later versions generally mention the fact) then according to the XPath spec, the result is a node-set, and a node-set is literally a set of nodes with no defined order. However, all implementations I know of return the results of the node-set in document order, because that is how XSLT requires them, and most XPath implementations are designed with XSLT as an important use case. So the `Reader` elements are likely to be returned in the order that they are encountered when scanning the document in a forwards direction.

In XPath 3.1 you could return a sequence of nodes in a chosen order by writing

```
/ReaderDetails ! (Reader[Pin = "2325"], 
                  Reader[Pin = "2421"], 
                  Reader[Pin = "2424"])
```

or perhaps (if the required order is always "sorted by Pin number"),

```
   sort(/ReaderDetails/Reader[Pin = ('2325', '2421', '2424'), (),
        function($r) {number($r!Pin})
```

but to do that you will need to install a different XPath engine, such as Saxon/C.

It's not possible to return a sequence of nodes in non-document-order in XPath 1.0 because there is no such data type. The only collection data type in XPath 1.0 is the node-set, which as I mentioned has no prescribed order. Therefore your only option with XPath 1.0 is to retrieve the nodes one at a time using separate XPath expressions, or perhaps to sort the nodes within the calling application.